# mysql SELECT AVG() gives different result

Tags: mysql, select, average

I tried to calculate the average in two different ways. The result should be the same, but mysql gives different result.

data dummy

```
CREATE TABLE `test_avg` (
  `dt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `field1` double NOT NULL,
  `field2` double NOT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `test_avg` (`dt`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES
('2022-10-31',  16.1379,    13.0809,    'A'),
('2022-10-31',  12.7579,    0.4458, 'A'),
('2022-10-31',  7.9206, 2.7775, 'A'),
('2022-10-31',  6.3764, 2.666,  'A'),
('2022-10-31',  5.3136, 1.6478, 'A'),
('2022-10-31',  4.5103, 88.178, 'A'),
('2022-10-31',  4.3547, 7.813,  'A'),
('2022-10-31',  4.3542, 3.5463, 'A'),
('2022-10-31',  3.0554, 7.3114, 'A'),
('2022-10-31',  26.3792,    2.2424, 'B'),
('2022-10-31',  9.6861, 28.5324,    'B'),
('2022-10-31',  9.1814, 6.8606, 'B'),
('2022-10-31',  8.0094, 6.2568, 'B'),
('2022-10-31',  7.5882, 548.5715,   'B'),
('2022-10-31',  7.5301, 3.7209, 'B'),
('2022-10-31',  7.4933, 1.3494, 'B'),
('2022-10-31',  7.4388, 22.8762,    'B'),
('2022-10-31',  7.1385, 19.9597,    'B'),
('2022-10-31',  7.1196, 19.8701,    'B');
```

query1

```
SELECT dt, AVG(field1), AVG(field2)
FROM test_avg
GROUP BY dt
```

query2

```
SELECT a.dt, AVG(a.avg1), AVG(a.avg2)
FROM
(SELECT dt, AVG(field1)AS avg1, AVG(field2)AS avg2, field3
FROM test_avg
GROUP BY dt, field3)a
GROUP BY a.dt
```

The result should be the same, but mysql gives different result.

Comment: Your query2 means `avg of (avg of A and avg of B)` = `(avg of A + avg of B)/2` , of course it's different with query1

Comment: Add count(*) to show rows used in avg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An average of averages is different from the average of the individual figures as soon as subsample sizes differ:

```
(10 + 20 + 60 + 50 + 25) / 5 = 33
```

But:

```
(10 + 20 + 60) / 3 = 30
(50 + 25) / 2 = 37.5
(30 + 37.5) / 2 = 33.75
```

The reason is that the weight of original values is being changed in the process.

Comment: thank you very much. this is new knowledge for me.